# What is wrong with my SwiftUI view not updating?

Tags: macos, swiftui, view

I'm trying to use the basic @State/@Binding method op updating a View parameter but it doesn't work. Here is the View code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StreamingImageView: View {
    @State var imageURL: URL = URL(string: "file:\(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])/../img_01.jpg")!
    var body: some View {
        let _ = FileMonitor(fileURL: $imageURL)
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            AsyncImage(url: imageURL)
                .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

FileMonitor re-assigns the imageURL when the image has been refreshed(this is verified). However, I do not see the displayed view updated.

Here is the code in FileMonitor:

```
class FileMonitor {
    @Binding var fileURL: URL
    let localFileURL: URL
    let fileDescriptor: CInt
    let fileMonitorQueue: DispatchQueue
    let fileMonitorSource: DispatchSourceFileSystemObject

    init(fileURL: Binding<URL>) {
        localFileURL = URL(string: fileURL.wrappedValue.path)!
        self._fileURL = fileURL
        fileDescriptor = open(fileURL.wrappedValue.path(), O_EVTONLY)
        fileMonitorQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "GB.IndigoPolarAlignAid_filemonitor")
        fileMonitorSource = DispatchSource.makeFileSystemObjectSource(fileDescriptor: fileDescriptor, eventMask: .write, queue: fileMonitorQueue)
        startMonitoring()
    }

    func startMonitoring() {
        fileMonitorSource.setEventHandler {
            print("File has been written!")
            // Perform any desired actions here
            self.fileURL = self.localFileURL
        }
...
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to do procedural code inside your view hierarchy. Among other problems, your `FileMonitor` will immediately go out of scope. Consider using a `StateObject` and triggering the monitoring via `onAppear` or `task`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was having a lot of trouble with procedural code in the View - always getting some error but I'll work on it. I wasn't user StateObject was available yet but I'll give it a try!

Comment: Binding Is only for SwiftUI views and DynamicProperty  it doesn’t work in a class

Comment: That's really frustrating to hear. Every time I try to use these "convenient" Swift features, I either get errors or can't be used or parameters are incompatible. I've tried so many variants of this. I'm surprised that this code would compile and run yet not work as you say. Very frustrating.

Comment: These aren't "Swift" wrappers they are "SwiftUI" wrappers. You should try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials, if you come from another language it would help you find the differences. SwiftUI is a very strict framework, it does a lot for you in terms of UI but everything has to be in place just right. As you can see `body` is a computed property, it gets redrawn at very specific times in a very specific way only controlled by SwiftUI you have to work with that,

Comment: I went through many tutorials but I'm still having problems of course. I'm not a real software programmer - the languages I know best are HDL languages used for designing chips, but every now and then I dabble in software. I actually wondered about using the class as I did and checked into it but thought it was ok. You mention SwiftUI is a strict framework. This is why I gave up trying to use procedural code in it. Ran into too many problems there too, so I tried to put the procedural code in the FileMonitor class. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: I simplified this issue and moved it to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78008890/how-to-get-asyncimage-to-update-the-view-with-changing-image