# How to get AsyncImage to update the View with changing image

Tags: macos, swiftui, view

I'm using an observable object to cause the update of a view - an image file is being updated every second by a driver. But the actual image is not updated, only the opacity property - I was just using opacity to see the change. I was expecting the whole view including the image itself to be updated with a change in the observed object.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StreamingImageView: View {
    var filePath = URL(string: "file:/Users/\(NSUserName())/Library/Containers/GB.IndigoPolarAlignAid/Data/img_01.jpg")
    @ObservedObject var monitor: FileMonitor
    
    init(){
        print("StreamingImageView: \(filePath!)")
        monitor = FileMonitor(filePath: filePath!)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            AsyncImage(url: filePath)
                .opacity(Double(monitor.fileUpdateCount)/10.0)
            Text("count \(monitor.fileUpdateCount) \(filePath!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]. In general, I'll say that using an `init` to create an `ObservableObject` is not advised. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC to get more of an idea about how the framework works.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the creation of the ObservableObject - still not change in behaviour. Creating an MRE is difficult because I would have create a changing image in a safe place in a sandbox. It was hard enough getting it to work on my machine.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how anyone can diagnose what's going on without at least seeing `FileMonitor`

Comment: try using `@State private var filePath = URL...`, and elsewhere in your code change that value, and the UI will update. Alternatively, use  `AsyncImage(url: monitor.filePath)` directly, since this is the observed model.

Comment: You are using `URL(string:)` to read a local file?

Comment: @jnpdx the observed property monitor.fileUpdateCount is definitely seen to be updating because the image opacity is updated - also I see the console state that the jpg file that comes from a camera has been written. But the SwiftUI is not reloading the jpg file itself.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, I'm trying your suggestions but having trouble... working on it.

Comment: @ElTomato yes, the local file is written by a camera driver, once per second. I've checked that the file is overwritten each second.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, I'm trying your suggestions to use monitor.filePath but I guess since in fact the path does not change, the image is not changed either.

Comment: So you’re just writing a new file to the disk and expecting SwiftUI to know that it changed and read and render the new file? SwiftUI doesn’t watch the file system, so that explains why it isn’t working. You could try adding a unique `id` property to the AsyncImage every time you want it to re-read

Comment: @jnpdx The fileMonitor monitors the writing of the file and updates fileUpdateCount which is applied to the opacity property of AsyncImage. Consequently, the display IS updated in that the opacity is updated but AsyncImage does not reload the jpg as expected. SwiftUI is supposed re-render everything required for the view - at least that is what they say but of course that is not what is happening. You say to use the id property... this is what the codementor guy showed me but admitted that it was a bit of a hack so I wanted to know how it should be done properly.

Comment: SwiftUI re-renders it determines need to be re rendered. If you don’t change the file path, it would have no reason to reload and re render the image.

Comment: Thank you @jnpdx The adding the id property works although the display seems to flash a bit. I added this line: `.id(monitor.fileUpdateCount)` I guess I'm satisfied with this fix. It doesn't seem to be a hack and works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by @jnpdx - in the discussion above - who suggested adding a unique `id` property - I used the monitor.fileUpdateCount to do this and get an updated display with refreshed jpg as I wanted. Here is minimal code that works:

```
import SwiftUI

let filePath = URL(string: "file:/Users/\(NSUserName())/Library/Containers/GB.IndigoPolarAlignAid/Data/img_01.jpg")

struct StreamingImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var monitor: FileMonitor = FileMonitor(filePath: filePath!)
    var id: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
            AsyncImage(url: monitor.filePath)
                    .id(monitor.fileUpdateCount)
}
```